# How can I limit total quota using squid without authentication for per user

Tags: debian, wifi, squid, quota, limits

I am having Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, I have configured it as a wifi hotspot using hostapd and dhcpd, I have configured transparent squid proxy server on it. Now all traffic goes through my proxy server and I can see a log in ***/var/log/squid3/access.log***. I need to keep the track of data for user connected to my wifi, I need to keep how much data he has used for e.g x.x.x.x has used 200MB and I need to ban that user after using 500MB. How can I achieve this with transparent proxy server and without using authentication.
I tried with squish but no success as I guess it needs authentication.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @MadHatter I think the post you suggested is focused on speed and not quota limit i.e total data used for eg: 1GB

Comment: @MadHatter I have edited the question, Thanks for suggestion.